# Merging feature from deleted branch with TortoiseSVN is not working as expected

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn, branch

I deleted a branch a long time ago, and of course now I need to merge that feature into another branch.  :)

I'm using TortoiseSVN, and I think I'm doing it the right way.  I have changed the revision of the repo browser to the correct revision that has my branch right before it was deleted.

[image]

I then selected the range to merge, and it auto-filled the revision text to include the peg revision.  But when I test the merge, it says, "path not found".

Is there something else I could be doing wrong here?  I'm using TortoiseSVN 1.7.12, Build 24070 - 64 Bit.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer - you need to put the peg revision (ie the one just before you deleted the branch) in the URL you're merging from. You specify this with the @ symbol.

So say http://server.com/svn/branch@1234 instead of changing the 'snapshot' revision using the button. That button affects the destination too, which doesn't exist when you go 'back in time' like that.

TortoiseSVN docs have a much more [detailed tutorial](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-merge.html) on doing this. I do think TortoiseSVN could make it more obvious - you need to specify the peg revision of the range to merge where I think this is obvious (ie if you merge rev 2, you're merging rev 2 no matter what snapshot view of the repo).

Still, the simple answer is to put the peg revision on the end of both URL and revision range.

Comment: I had already tried that as well by manually adding it, but it still gave me "path not found".  However, I didn't try having it in both the URL and the revision range.  I'll play around with it some more and will also look up the docs.  RTFM I guess!   Thanks.

Comment: Ok, found the info in the docs here: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-merge.html.  The important part is this: ` With the command line client you specify the changes to merge using two “fence post” revisions which specify the before and after points.

With TortoiseSVN you specify the changeset to merge using “fence panels”.`  So I think the problem was that I picked the wrong starting revision number.  Gonna try that now!